# GCD of elementary symmetric functions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It is easy to show that p/ $\sigma_j$ ( where $\sigma_j$ is the sum of all products of j distinct members of the set {1,2,...,p-1}) for all $1 \leq j \leq p-2$, but how would you go about showing that the greatest common divisor of $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,...,\sigma_{p-2}$ is in fact p itself?

My first thought was to consider $
\sigma_1 = 1+2+3+\cdots p-1=\frac{p(p-1)}{2}$.  Since we know that p divides each $\sigma_j$, we consider $\frac{\sigma_j}{p}=\frac{p-1}{2}$.  Now if I can show that no prime dividor of $\frac{p-1}{2}$ divides any other $
\sigma_j$, then I'm done.  However, I've run into problems with this and I am not entirely sure this is the proper way to approach the problem.  Any suggestions would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** We want to show that if $q$ is a prime factor of $p-1$, then $q \nmid \sigma_i$ for some $i$. Consider

$$(x-1)(x-2) \ldots (x-(p-1)) \equiv [x(x-1) \ldots (x-(q-1))]^{\frac{p-1}{q}} \pmod{q}$$

**Hint 2:** We have $$(x-1)(x-2) \ldots (x-(p-1))=x^{p-1}+\sum_{i=1}^{p-2}{\sigma_i(-1)^ix^{p-1-i}}+(-1)^{p-1}(p-1)!$$

If $q$ were to divide $\sigma_i$ for all $i$, then the above will be congruent to $x^{p-1} \pmod{q}$. Can $[x(x-1) \ldots (x-(q-1))]^{\frac{p-1}{q}}$ be congruent to $x^{p-1} \pmod{q}$?

Comment: I've been fooling around with this for a while now, but have not been able to come up with anything of use.  I must be missing the connection between the two sides of the congruence, what could I look at to help me see where it comes from?

Comment: $[x(x-1)...(x-(q-1))]^{\frac{p-1}{q}}$ is always congruent to 0 (mod q), so is never $x^{p-1}$ unless $x\equiv 0$ (mod $q$)?

Comment: @user70363 Indeed. As you noticed, $[x(x-1) \ldots (x-(q-1))]^{\frac{p-1}{q}}$ is always congruent to $0 \pmod{q}$, while $x^{p-1}$ can only be congruent to $0 \pmod{q}$ when $x \equiv 0 \pmod{q}$. Thus they cannot be the same $\pmod{q}$, so we cannot have $q \mid \sigma_i$ for all $i$.

Comment: Great! I still have some gaps though.  I wasn't able to prove the first congruence.  Is it something simple that I just haven't noticed?  Where does it come from exactly?

Comment: @user70363 You mean the one in my first hint? Well $$(x-1)(x-2) \ldots (x-(p-1))=\prod_{i=0}^{\frac{p-1}{q}-1}{[(x-(iq+1))(x-(iq+2)) \ldots (x-(iq+q))]} \equiv [x(x-1) \ldots (x-(q-1))]^{\frac{p-1}{q}} \pmod{q}$$